# c# EF Core 5 enforce one to many relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I have a database relationship that I would like to be one to many in EFCore 5. Currently it is enforced through our UI and data model on "scouts honor". Is there a good way to generate a migration that would create an index to create a unique key constraint on my 1 side of the table so it would error out at the database level instead of having a chance of accidentally creating a many to many? It would be amazing if there was some type of attribute or way I could handle this in a code first way, because I have over 20 of these to define and would prefer a code first approach rather than just adding a constraint to the db or update the OnModelCreating by hand every time.

For example, I would like to enforce that a customerperson can have zero or one survey response

```
    public class CustomerPerson
    {
        public Guid ID { get; set; }

        public Guid SurveyResponseID { get; set; }
        public SurveyResponse SurveyResponse { get; set; } // navigation property
    }

    public class SurveyResponse
    {
        public Guid ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100)]
        [DisplayName("Indicate OveraallSatisfaction")]
        public string Satisfaction { get; set; }

        public string Comments { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: unique key constraint? isn't many side referencing the PK (primary key) of the one side?

Comment: okay, so if I add a unique key constraint on the many side, that would enforce the 1 side of the one to many. This is what I had in mind, but Idk how to do this with ef core

Comment: If you add *unique* constraint at many side FK, it won't be "many" anymore, but "one" (one-to-one)

Comment: Actually it is possible to create and reference another unique key (aka [alternate key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations#alternate-keys)) on 1 side of the relationship. I'm just not sure what is your case, maybe providing sample of your existing model (2 entities and related fields) would help understanding what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: I added an example. I am using dummy entities but it illustrates what I am trying to do. My apologies for the confusion, communication is not my strong suit

Comment: so, what you wanna do exactly ? if you are looking for one to oneORzero relationship i can help but i dont understand how to enforce in the way that you want :(

Comment: No problem, neither is mine :-) Let see. Looks like you really are seeking for one-to-one. `SurveyResponse` (principal) 1 to 0..1 CustomerPerson (dependent). From the other side it is `CutomerPerson` (dependent) 1 to 1 `SurveyResponse` (principal). All these terms are from EF Core [Relationships](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key). If you really want "customerperson can have zero or one survey response:, then `SurveyResponseID` must be changed to nullable (`Guid?`). It both cases it needs fluent configuration.

Comment: ... since no data annotation (attribute) exists for configuring such relationship. If you search SO, you'll probably find an example, even mine, but in general you need something like `modelBuilder.Entity<CustomerPerson>().HasOne(e => e.SurveyResponse).WithOne().HasForeignKey<CustomerPerson>(e => e.SurveyResponseID)` (the last is essential). Btw, fluent API is code first, so you need to write it just once, and then generate migration from the configured model.